# Counting Collisions Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, sprite

So my code is counting the collisions but its adding 4 to the score label everytime. Its suppose to only add 1, can anybody see my error? Thank you.

This is the collision detection

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair eggCollision:(CCNode *)egg dinoCollision:(CCNode *)dino
{

[egg removeFromParent];

lifes--;
[lifeslabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lifes: %d", lifes]];

return YES;
}
```

now this is the code for the egg and its physics body

```
- (void)addEgg:(CCTime)dt
{
egg = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"egg.png"];

int minX = egg.contentSize.height/2 - egg.contentSize.height/2;
int maxX = self.contentSize.height;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int randomX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

egg.position = CGPointMake(randomX, self.contentSize.height + egg.contentSize.height/2);
egg.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, egg.contentSize} cornerRadius:0];
egg.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"eggGroup";
egg.physicsBody.collisionType  = @"eggCollision";
[_physicsWorld addChild:egg];
}
```

Breakpoint -

[image]

Comment: The code looks fine in general. Can you debug and check that you don't add four egg objects on top of each other? Can you set a breakpoint in `ccPhysicsCollisionBegin` and check if the collision occurs with four different egg instances?

Comment: I added a picture of what comes up @Ben-G

Comment: I had a similar problem. If you are using gravity, it seems like it collides more than 1 time, even when you see that it only does it once. I don't know a solution for this, but you can try to add a flag, and if that flag (objects have collided at least once) is true, don't add more to the label. Hope it helps